# Looking for workaround where Google Sheets QUERY function turns numbers into text . .

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been researching all morning and haven't been able to find a way to make this work. [Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ASnot8XD_yk1hzuKMHhb2XUL23-x-rvnvVMEPqb8-Ys/edit?usp=sharing) I have a form (created as a student test) that feeds a spreadsheet with 160+ questions; therefore columns. I'm using a transpose/query function to bring the data into another tab so I can begin the analysis. The problem is, when the data comes into the new tab `=query(transpose(query('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$FF$2,"Select *",1)))`, it turns all the numeric scores into text. I believe it does this because there are string values as well.  I would like to filter those out, but no luck there either. Does anyone know of a work-around for this? Or can recommend a better way?  THANK YOU!

Comment: The data in your response sheet is coming in as '01 which forces it to be a string and not an integer.  Can you change the form so the response is a number?

Comment: Only the student grade is coming in as '01. Sometimes it may be KG for kindergarten or PK for preschool. Is it because it sees that and then makes all the other numbers follow suite? Hmmm. I'll look a little closer at that. Thank you Krispin.

Comment: I forgot I do have other text in the row.  The option for a teacher to go back to previous grade questions. Is there a way when writing the query function - to only pull numeric values and ignore the text?

Comment: Not sure in this particular instance, but there is the function ISNUMBER() that returns true / false if the cell is a number.

Comment: I decided to look at something else (SumIfs with Index and Match) to try and get to the same place.  I added a 3rd tab onto the attached spreadsheet. I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do makes sense? But it doesn't work. I also tried doing a horizontal/vertical SumIfs but again, I keep running into Errors.  This is what I current have and it's giving me an error of 'Argument must be a range,' and it looks like a range to me:  =sumifs(index('Form Responses 1'!$C$3:$FF$3,0,match($A$2,'Form Responses 1'!$C$2:$FF$2,0)),'Form Responses 1'!C$3:FF$3,B$1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but if you just want to transpose the 'Form Responses 1' data and convert columns E and F to a numeric, then you could try the following.

Create a new tab called 'Cleaned'.

In cell A1 enter `={'Form Responses 1'!A1:FN1}`

or to remove 'Option ' from the headings:

`=arrayformula(substitute({'Form Responses 1'!A1:FN1},"Option ",""))`

In cell A2 enter `=arrayformula({'Form Responses 1'!A2:D,value('Form Responses 1'!E2:F),'Form Responses 1'!G2:FN})`

Then on your 'Transpose Data' tab, in cell A1, enter:

`=transpose(Cleaned!$A$1:$F$5)`

In cell A7, enter:

`=transpose(Cleaned!$G$1:$FF$5)` * see below

Make sure there are no formulas below cell A7 or in columns B to E.

*If you want unique values in the transposed columns A to E, then in cell A7 use:

`unique(transpose(Cleaned!$G$1:$FF$5))`

If you only want unique values in column A, then you could create another tab, say 'Transpose Data2':

In cell A1:

`=unique('Transpose Data'!A:A)`

In cell B1:

`=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(A1:A,{'Transpose Data'!A:E},{2,3,4,5,6},false),""))`

It won't keep your G1, G2, G3 rows together, but that will need a sort column creating on the 'Transpose Data' tab.